# Vue / Vuetify: Move layout when mobile keyboard shown (avoid keyboard overlap)

Tags: vue.js, mobile, browser, keyboard, vuetify.js

I wonder if there is a way / feature in `Vuetify` to move the layout up, when an input field (e.g. `v-text-field` or `v-input`) is clicked and the keyboard shows up on the mobile device's browser?

Like seen on the image below, which shows the behavior of a native mobile app:

[image]